# Excel online workbook cache local file which is password protected - content.mso

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, office365, sharepoint

We are going through the process of moving our files to sharepoint, a few of our workbooks are linked to other workbooks which are all password protected.

When I open Workbook 1 which is linked to workbook 2 it asks me for the password to open the workbook which is fine, but after opening because it is linked to workbook 2 it presents another popup asking to enter password but its for a local cached file located in INETCache\Content.MSO

Now i know the password and which workbooks are linked to each other, but others certainly do not..... how do we stop this local caching from happening? Can we delete the folder...will it cause issues on office 365?

See pic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwg1f.png)

Comment: Can you unprotect the Workbook directly:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/protect-an-excel-file-7359d4ae-7213-4ac2-b058-f75e9311b599

Comment: The workbooks need to be password protected for security reasons...not sure what you are asking? @lee

Comment: I am guessing this is the temporary copy of workbook2 that excel downloads a fresh when you open workbook1. If you enter the password of workbook2 does it work? If so I wouldn't worry about it. Local caching has to be done in most cases. And since its password protected the risk to the data, even if the person's computer is stolen, is mitigated.